# Updating a vertex buffer causes a debug layer error

Tags: c++, directx-12

I updated my Windows 10 to version 1607 which includes additional D3D debug layer checking. My vertex buffer updating code worked without warnings/errors before the update, but now I'm getting an error when calling `CopyBufferRegion`:

> Resource state (0xAC3: D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_GENERIC_READ) of resource
>   (0x000001DB301B9750:'') (subresource: 0) is
>   invalid for use as a destination buffer.  Expected State Bits: 0x400:
>   D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_COPY_DEST, Actual State: 0xAC3:
>   D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_GENERIC_READ

If I transition `vb` into the wanted state (`D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_COPY_DEST`) I instead get an error like this:

> D3D12 ERROR: ID3D12CommandList::ResourceBarrier: Certain heaps are
>   restricted to certain D3D12_RESOURCE_STATES states, and cannot be
>   changed. D3D12_HEAP_TYPE_UPLOAD requires
>   D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_GENERIC_READ. D3D12_HEAP_TYPE_READBACK requires
>   D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_COPY_DEST.  [ RESOURCE_MANIPULATION ERROR #741:
>   RESOURCE_BARRIER_INVALID_HEAP]

Here is my code. It creates a vertex buffer and uploads vertex data, resizing the buffer if necessary:

```
void ae3d::VertexBuffer::UploadVB( void* faces, void* vertices, unsigned ibSize )
{
    D3D12_HEAP_PROPERTIES uploadProp = {};
    uploadProp.Type = D3D12_HEAP_TYPE_UPLOAD;
    uploadProp.CPUPageProperty = D3D12_CPU_PAGE_PROPERTY_UNKNOWN;
    uploadProp.MemoryPoolPreference = D3D12_MEMORY_POOL_UNKNOWN;
    uploadProp.CreationNodeMask = 1;
    uploadProp.VisibleNodeMask = 1;

    D3D12_RESOURCE_DESC bufferProp = {};
    bufferProp.Alignment = 0;
    bufferProp.DepthOrArraySize = 1;
    bufferProp.Dimension = D3D12_RESOURCE_DIMENSION_BUFFER;
    bufferProp.Flags = D3D12_RESOURCE_FLAG_NONE;
    bufferProp.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_UNKNOWN;
    bufferProp.Height = 1;
    bufferProp.Layout = D3D12_TEXTURE_LAYOUT_ROW_MAJOR;
    bufferProp.MipLevels = 1;
    bufferProp.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    bufferProp.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    bufferProp.Width = ibOffset + ibSize;

    // this branch resizes the buffer and causes validation errors.
    if (vb != nullptr && bufferProp.Width <= sizeBytes)
    {
        ID3D12Resource* stagingBuffer = nullptr;

        HRESULT hr = GfxDeviceGlobal::device->CreateCommittedResource( &uploadProp, D3D12_HEAP_FLAG_NONE, &bufferProp,
            D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_GENERIC_READ, nullptr, IID_PPV_ARGS( &stagingBuffer ) );
        AE3D_CHECK_D3D( hr, "Failed to create vertex staging resource" );

        char* vbUploadPtr = nullptr;
        hr = stagingBuffer->Map( 0, nullptr, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&vbUploadPtr) );
        if (FAILED( hr ))
        {
            ae3d::System::Assert( false, "Unable to map vertex staging buffer!\n" );
            return;
        }

        memcpy_s( vbUploadPtr, ibOffset, vertices, ibOffset );
        memcpy_s( vbUploadPtr + ibOffset, ibSize, faces, ibSize );

        stagingBuffer->Unmap( 0, nullptr );


        // vb state is invalid at this point, needs D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_COPY_DEST
        GfxDeviceGlobal::graphicsCommandList->CopyBufferRegion( vb, 0, stagingBuffer, 0, ibOffset + ibSize );

        Global::frameVBUploads.push_back( stagingBuffer );
        sizeBytes = ibOffset + ibSize;

        return;
    }

    sizeBytes = ibOffset + ibSize;

    HRESULT hr = GfxDeviceGlobal::device->CreateCommittedResource(
        &uploadProp,
        D3D12_HEAP_FLAG_NONE,
        &bufferProp,
        D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_GENERIC_READ,
        nullptr,
        IID_PPV_ARGS( &vb ) );
    if (FAILED( hr ))
    {
        ae3d::System::Assert( false, "Unable to create vertex buffer!\n" );
        return;
    }

    Global::vbs.push_back( vb );

    char* vbUploadPtr = nullptr;
    hr = vb->Map( 0, nullptr, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&vbUploadPtr) );
    if (FAILED( hr ))
    {
        ae3d::System::Assert( false, "Unable to map vertex buffer!\n" );
        return;
    }

    memcpy_s( vbUploadPtr, ibOffset, vertices, ibOffset );
    memcpy_s( vbUploadPtr + ibOffset, ibSize, faces, ibSize );
    vb->Unmap( 0, nullptr );
}
```

How can I fix these debug layer errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upload buffer can only be in `D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_GENERIC_READ` state ([link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn899226(v=vs.85).aspx#Initial_states_for_resources)). You need to create a default buffer with `D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_COPY_DEST` state. Then after mapping of upload heap on cpu you can copy contents of upload buffer to default buffer on gpu with [ID3D12GraphicsCommandList::CopyBufferRegion()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn903856(v=vs.85).aspx) method. Don't forget to transition default buffer to usable state after and be sure that upload heap still exist at the moment the gpu executed the copying.

Comment: Thanks, but could you be a little more specific as to how to apply that into my question's code? Specifically the buffer and heap creation parameters. I also don't understand the default buffer creation, should I replace one of my current code's buffers with it or create a new buffer?

Comment: You can find an example [here](https://github.com/d3dcoder/d3d12book/blob/master/Common/d3dUtil.cpp#L38). Basically you need 2 buffers - default that should live until you don't need vertex buffer anymore and upload that should live until you copy from it.